# Cycle through list starting at a certain element

Tags: python, list, cycle

Say I have a list:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I want to cycle through it. Normally, it would do something like this,

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2...
```

I want to be able to start at a certain point in the cycle, not necessarily an index, but perhaps matching an element. Say I wanted to start at whatever element in the list `==4`, then the output would be,

```
4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1...
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at [itertools](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html) module. It provides all the necessary functionality.

```
from itertools import cycle, islice, dropwhile

L = [1, 2, 3, 4]

cycled = cycle(L)  # cycle thorugh the list 'L'
skipped = dropwhile(lambda x: x != 4, cycled)  # drop the values until x==4
sliced = islice(skipped, None, 10)  # take the first 10 values

result = list(sliced)  # create a list from iterator
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Comment: `dropwhile` doesn't seem necessary here. You can instead use `list(islice(cycled, L.index(4), L.index(4) + 9))`

Answer (score 20):

Use the arithmetic `mod` operator. Suppose you're starting from position `k`, then `k` should be updated like this:

```
k = (k + 1) % len(l)
```

If you want to start from a certain element, not index, you can always look it up like `k = l.index(x)` where x is the desired item.

Answer (score 5):

I'm not such a big fan of importing modules when you can do things by your own in a couple of lines. Here's my solution without imports:

```
def cycle(my_list, start_at=None):
    start_at = 0 if start_at is None else my_list.index(start_at)
    while True:
        yield my_list[start_at]
        start_at = (start_at + 1) % len(my_list)
```

This will return an (infinite) iterator looping your list. To get the next element in the cycle you must use the `next` statement:

```
>>> it1 = cycle([101,102,103,104])
>>> next(it1), next(it1), next(it1), next(it1), next(it1)
(101, 102, 103, 104, 101) # and so on ...
>>> it1 = cycle([101,102,103,104], start_at=103)
>>> next(it1), next(it1), next(it1), next(it1), next(it1)
(103, 104, 101, 102, 103) # and so on ...
```

Comment: `itertools` is written in `C`. So, it's quite fast apart from its eloquence.

Comment: I like this answer best.

Answer (score 2):

```
import itertools as it
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list(it.islice(it.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 4, it.cycle(l)),  10))
# returns: [4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

so the iterator you want is:

```
it.dropwhile(lambda x: x != 4, it.cycle(l))
```

Comment: @gnibbler It would take to put `4` in parenthesis `(4).__cmp__`. Otherwise it doesn't work (at least in Python 2.7.2). And with parenthesis it doesn't look that beautiful.

Comment: @gnibbler And as of Python 3 it would take to use `__eq__` instead of `__cmp__` (there is no `__cmp__` as of the version 3).

Comment: @ovgolovin What @gnibbler wrote works without parentheses. Did you miss the space between `4` and `.`?

Comment: @ovgolovin for Python 3 it should be `__ne__` or `__gt__` rather than `__eq__`.

Comment: space between 4 and . ? what the heck is going on there?

Comment: @wim, if you write `4.__cmp__` Python will parse it as a floating point number `4.` followed by an identifier `__cmp__` and that's a syntax error. `4 .__cmp__` on the other hand is the integer `4` followed by a period to indicate an attribute reference and the attribute `__cmp__`.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle doesn't have such a start element.

Maybe you just start the cycle anyway and drop the first elements that you don't like.

Answer (score 1):

Another weird option is that cycling through lists can be accomplished *backwards*. For instance:

```
# Run this once
myList = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'boom']
myItem = 'baz'

# Run this repeatedly to cycle through the list
if myItem in myList:
    myItem = myList[myList.index(myItem)-1]
    print myItem
```

Answer (score 1):

Can use something like this:

```
def my_cycle(data, start=None):
  k = 0 if not start else start
  while True:
    yield data[k]
    k = (k + 1) % len(data)
```

Then run:

```
for val in my_cycle([0,1,2,3], 2):
  print(val)
```

Essentially the same as one of the previous answers. My bad.