# Is there a pythonic way to sample N consecutive elements from a list or numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, sample

Is there a pythonic way to select N consecutive elements from a list or numpy array.

So Suppose:

```
Choice = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I would like to create a new list of length N by randomly selecting element X in Choice along with the N-1 consecutive elements following choice.

So if:

```
X = 4 
N = 4
```

The resulting list would be:

```
Selection = [5,6,1,2]
```

I think something similar to the following would work.

```
S = [] 
for i in range(X,X+N):
    S.append(Selection[i%6])
```

But I was wondering if there is a python or numpy function that can select the elements at once that was more efficient.

Comment: How big can `N` be?

Comment: why not just randomly choose a starting index from [0, len(choices) - N)?

Comment: Check out the [slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation): `my_list[1:3]`. You will need to figure out the logic if you consider the list circular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cycle through list starting at a certain element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8940737/cycle-through-list-starting-at-a-certain-element)

Comment: @alkasm thanks that's a great idea.  Wanted to preserve the permutation and not sure how to sort it if it wasn't sequential.

Comment: Can `N` be bigger than `len(Choice)`?

Comment: Oh sorry @Nick, as you can see i'm a noob and didn't really understand the significance of your question...i think in most cases it will be less than len(Choice).  Does that create different solutions?

Comment: @phntm yes, if `N <= len(Choice)` the answer can be much simpler. See the edit to my answer

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `itertools`, specifically `islice` and `cycle`.

```
start = random.randint(0, len(Choice) - 1)
list(islice(cycle(Choice), start, start + n))
```

`cycle(Choice)` is an infinite sequence that repeats your original list, so that the slice `start:start + n` will wrap if necessary.

Comment: This is awesome thanks!  Is using itertools generally faster than numpy?

Comment: @phntm: For large inputs, it's almost guaranteed to be slower than any other solution, as it's `O(n)` on both memory usage and processing time (`islice` can't skip values, `cycle` stores them all until the input is exhausted). For small inputs, it hardly matters what solution you use.

Answer (score 4):

You could use a list comprehension, using modulo operations on the index to keep it in range of the list:

```py
Choice = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
X = 4 
N = 4
L = len(Choice)
Selection = [Choice[i % L] for i in range(X, X+N)]
print(Selection)
```

Output

```
[5, 6, 1, 2]
```

Note that if `N` is less than or equal to `len(Choice)`, you can greatly simplify the code:

```py
Choice = [1,2,3,4,5,6] 
X = 4 
N = 4
L = len(Choice)
Selection = Choice[X:X+N] if X+N <= L else Choice[X:] + Choice[:X+N-L]
print(Selection)
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you are asking for the most efficient way I created a little benchmark to test the solutions proposed in this thread.

I rewrote your current solution as:

```py
def op(choice, x):
    n = len(choice)
    selection = []
    for i in range(x, x + n):
        selection.append(choice[i % n])
    return selection
```

Where `choice` is the input list and `x` is the random index.

These are the results if `choice` contains 1_000_000 random numbers:

```
chepner: 0.10840400000000017 s
nick: 0.2066781999999998 s
op: 0.25887470000000024 s
fountainhead: 0.3679908000000003 s
```

### Full code

```
import random
from itertools import cycle, islice
from time import perf_counter as pc
import numpy as np


def op(choice, x):
    n = len(choice)
    selection = []
    for i in range(x, x + n):
        selection.append(choice[i % n])
    return selection


def nick(choice, x):
    n = len(choice)
    return [choice[i % n] for i in range(x, x + n)]


def fountainhead(choice, x):
    n = len(choice)
    return np.take(choice, range(x, x + n), mode='wrap')


def chepner(choice, x):
    n = len(choice)
    return list(islice(cycle(choice), x, x + n))


results = []
n = 1_000_000
choice = random.sample(range(n), n)
x = random.randint(0, n - 1)

# Correctness
assert op(choice, x) == nick(choice,x) == chepner(choice,x) == list(fountainhead(choice,x))

# Benchmark
for f in op, nick, chepner, fountainhead:
    t0 = pc()
    f(choice, x)
    t1 = pc()
    results.append((t1 - t0, f))

for t, f in sorted(results):
    print(f'{f.__name__}: {t} s')
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time - it's always interesting to see performance results.

Comment: Interestingly on my computer, for 1,000,000 entries the advantage of `chepner` is only about 15-20%, and it decreases further as the list length gets longer. At shorter lengths (10k or less), `chepner` is more than 2x faster.

Comment: @Nick yes `chepner` solution seems the fastest for a `list`. For larger list size (>10^6) using an array as input (like `array('i', choice)`) is faster and takes less memory. If `choice` is a Numpy array then [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65912922/8484783) is the fastest regardless of the input size.

Answer (score 3):

If using a `numpy` array as the source, we could of course use `numpy` "fancy indexing".

So, if ChoiceArray is the `numpy` array equivalent of the list `Choice`, and if `L` is `len(Choice)` or `len(ChoiceArray)`:

```
Selection = ChoiceArray [np.arange(X, N+X) % L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a `numpy` approach:

```
import numpy as np

Selection = np.take(Choice, range(X,N+X), mode='wrap')
```

Works even if `Choice` is a Python list rather than a `numpy` array.

Comment: Thanks this is really helpful!   Is there a difference in terms of using np.random.default_rng vs np.random.choice?

Comment: @phntm - Yes there are differences. I think [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599149/what-is-the-difference-between-numpy-randoms-generator-class-and-np-random-meth) discusses that